# How to show generated QR Code in generated PDF Django

Tags: django, qr-code, xhtml2pdf

I want to show generated qr code in my generated PDF but it doesn't show. If in html it's showed but not in pdf. I want to show qrcode in PDF without save it to media

Here is my code in views.py :

```
path_qr = 'localhost:8000/qrcode/detail/1'
qr = QRCode()
qr.add_data(path_qr)
img = qr.make_image()

data = {
  'qr_code': img
}

template = get_template(template_src)
html = template.render(data)
result = BytesIO()
pdf1 = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)

return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
```

And here is my code in html:

```
<img src="{{ qrcode }}" width="100" height="100">
```

Comment: What is `qrcode`, actually? My guess is that it's an `<img>` tag referring to some library-handled endpoint, and that pdf generation doesn't have access to the image. Inspect the html. You may find [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70345444/how-do-i-create-a-qr-code-in-python-without-saving-it-as-an-image) helpful in solving it.

Comment: Thanks bro, i've found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. I have to encode into b64. and its work

```
dataurl = 'data:image/png;base64,' + b64encode(qr_rend.getvalue()).decode('ascii')
```

so my code will be like this:

```
path_qr = 'localhost:8000/qrcode/detail/1'

qr_rend = BytesIO()
img = make(path_qr)
img.save(qr_rend, 'PNG')
dataurl = 'data:image/png;base64,' + b64encode(qr_rend.getvalue()).decode('ascii')
```

and in html like this:

```
<img src="{{ dataurl }}" width="100" height="100">
```